# Clean up the customer billing and shipping address in the Magento

Tags: magento

I want to delete all the address associated with the customer in the Magento(billing and shipping address). How can i do this programatically? Can somebody help me out?

I am using this code:

```
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

    $customer->loadByEmail((string) $_REQUEST['email']);

    $address = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

    $address->delete();
```

Answer (score 3):

Assumed that you have loaded the customers from the customer collection. Find the code below to load the customer addresses using the customer ID and delete it one by one.

```
    if($customer){
         /*Load the customer addresses by Customer Id*/
        $customerAddressCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/address_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',$customer->getId())->getItems();
        foreach($customerAddressCollection as $customerAddress){
            $customer_address_id = $customerAddress->getData('entity_id');
            if($customer_address_id!=""){   
      /*Load the Customer Address by ID and delete it*/    
               Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customer_address_id)->delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to delete the relation or delete all addresses?

## Relation

```
$col = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
foreach($col as $customer) {
    $address = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
    // set attributes
    $address->save();

    $address = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
    // set attributes
    $address->save();

}
```

## Delete all addresses

This is a bad idea, because there are a lot foreign keys on the addresses. Don't do that.

Comment: I want to delete the addresses and want to setup a new shipping and billing address..

Comment: Why delete them? Load and change them.

Comment: This is one of my motive. I want to do this. Can you help me?